# for loops with variable

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

the following gives me 5 hi:

```
for i in {1..5} ; 
do
echo hi $i
done
```

but when i do the following with variable, it wont:

```
num=5
for i in {1..$num} ; 
echo hihi $i
done
```

and i tried put some " " or  or ' ' around, but it still doesnt give me 5 hi, please give me some advice. the result return is {1..$num}, so please tell me how to set up a proper for situation with variable. thanks.

Comment: Variable expansion takes place after braces, so you can't use them inside. You can use seq if you want to use vars. i.e `for i in $(seq 1 $num)`

Comment: Don't use `seq`; it's inferior to, and no more standard than, a C-style `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is *Brace Expansion* happens much before *Parameter Expansion*, so the variable will not be expanded as you expected it to be.

Use a proper `C` style `for-loop`,

```
for ((i=1; i<=num; i++)); do
```

From `man bash` page, under `EXPANSION` section

> EXPANSION
>
> Expansion  is  performed  on  the command line after it has been split into words.  There are seven kinds of expansion performed.
>
> The order of expansions is: *`brace expansion`*; *`tilde expansion`*, *`parameter and variable expansion`*, *`arithmetic expansion`*, and *`command substitution`* (done in a left-to-right fashion); *`word splitting`*; and
>          *`pathname expansion`*.

Comment: Or `seq 1 $num`

Comment: @heemayl That requires a subshell though, so C for loop is probs best solution.